# Function-Local Static variable For Unique Id Generation

Tags: c++, c, thread-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ID generator with local static variable - thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705679/id-generator-with-local-static-variable-thread-safe)

Would the following function return a unique number every time it is called? What about in a multi-threaded scenario?

```
int returnUniqueNumber()
{
  static int i = 0;
  ++i;
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your platform as to ehwther you'll get multithreading issues.  On windows you'd be best off doing the following:

```
int returnUniqueNumber()
{
  volatile static long l = 0;
  return (int)InterlockedIncrement( &l );
}
```

The [Interlocked*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614(VS.85).aspx) functions are guaranteed atomic.

Comment: You should not cast the `static int *` to a `volatile long *`--rather, it should be a (appropriately qualified) `LONG *` in both cases, and cast to an `int` on return (or just implicitly by the function.) `long` and `int` (and Windows' `LONG` typedef) are not always the same size, and while this cast may be fine on Windows, it encourages bad habits. :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Point taken, Fixed.

Comment: I salute you, sir. +1 for you and +1 for simple accurate code!

Comment: After the int's maximum value is reached and then to -ve values, doesn't it rotate back to 0, 1, 2 ... ?

Comment: @riderchap: yes.  It will count up to 2^31 - 1 and then it will swap to -2^31 and count up to 0.  The loop continues ad infinitum.  This is the main bonus of twos complement encoding ...

Answer (score 3):

If your application were single-threaded, the code you posted would be in fact the correct, standards-compliant C/C++ way of generating unique numbers. However, since you're looking for a thread-safe solution, you must dive into platform-specific solutions. Goz has a good Windows solution. An equivalent on Mac OS X or iOS would be:

```
int returnUniqueNumber_APPLE(void) {
    static volatile int32_t i = 0;
    return (int)OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier(&i);
}
```

On any system where you compile with a recent-ish GCC, you also have GCC's intrinsics:

```
int returnUniqueNumber_GCC(void) {
    static volatile int i = 0;
    return __sync_add_and_fetch(&i, 1);
}
```

Comment: Looks like we've covered Windows, Linux & MacOS :)

Comment: Not just Linux, but most *NIXes. :) In fact, we've got pretty much every major modern system covered. Android might be the only one left, and there you can just throw a `synchronized` keyword before the function's return type and be done. (Does Java have proper atomic operations? And I don't mean `AtomicInteger` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Goz's answer regarding windows, for Linux/GCC see this question/answer:

[Equivalent of InterlockedIncrement in Linux/gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125937/equivalent-of-interlockedincrement-in-linux-gcc)

in which case you'll want `__sync_add_and_fetch()`